# Store an object that is accessible within a Server Request?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httpcontext, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC project, and I would like to lazy-load a database DataContext object that is used across `Class`es within a server Request (that is, it only live through a Request, and for each Request, I have an unique object).

Currently I can obtain the Request using `HttpContext.Current` or `HttpContext.Current.Request`, but the Request only stores string values.

Is there something like the `Session` object, but for the Request only? Something like the ViewBag or ViewData, but accessible from the `HttpContext` object?

EDIT: Here is what I am trying to achieve: I have a `AccountBusiness` class, that might be instantiated multiple times in a request. It has `LoggedInUser` property (note: this is not the AspNetUser object of ASP.NET Identity) that is lazy-loaded. Normally I would do something like this:

```
    private UserProfile loggedInProfile;
    public UserProfile LoggedInProfile
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.loggedInProfile == null)
            {
                var userId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
                this.loggedInProfile = this.Context.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(q => q.ID == userId);
            }

            return this.loggedInProfile;
        }
    }
```

However, as I stated before, this property might be instantiated multiple times in a request, it will access the database multiple time for just a same UserProfile object. This is just an example, I have much more objects similar to this, and would like to change so that it only access the database once, then save it for using for the current Request, like this:

```
    public UserProfile LoggedInProfile
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.loggedInProfile == null)
            {
                var dataTokens = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.DataTokens;
                object o;
                if (!dataTokens.TryGetValue("CurrentUserProfile", out o))
                {
                    var userId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
                    dataTokens["CurrentUserProfile"] = o = this.Context.UserProfiles
                        .FirstOrDefault(q => q.ID == userId);
                }
                this.loggedInProfile = o as UserProfile;
            }

            return this.loggedInProfile;
        }
    }
```

Is there any bad thing in my solution?

P.s: I just discover `RouteValues` and `DataTokens` may contain a `key-object` pair, but I wonder if it is okay to use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the HttpContext.Items collection to share objects during the lifetime of the request.

Comment: Thanks, this is actually what I need!

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to lazy-load a database DataContext object that is used across the Request only.

That bit troubles me. Perhaps it's just worded awkwardly, but it sounds as if you're somehow trying to persist your context across requests, which would be a *very* bad idea.

If, however, you're just talking about persisting the results of a query or similar, I'd recommend using the in-memory caching provided by ASP.NET. Using session or cookies involves relying on the client to store information, and that's both unnecessary and inappropriate for this kind of thing.

Comment: Sorry maybe my words are not correct and trouble you. I mean, I want to access it across the Controller, Models, etc... **within a request**. I know reusing `DataContext` object is bad. Also, beside DataContext, I would like to store a logged in User object too. I hope you understand my explanation now.

Comment: First, the Request object is still the wrong place for this as it would require a dependency on the Request object in places like your model that is totally inappropriate. Second, your models should not have a dependency on the context *at all*, regardless. Third, the User object is *already* in the request, so I'm not sure what more you would need there. Perhaps if you gave more background on exactly what you're trying to achieve and *why*, we could give you better guidance on how to proceed. The "why" is especially important. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have updated the question, please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cache or Cookie both are accessible with HttpContext and after using you can make empty them.

Comment: For `Cache` and `Cookie`, you have to manually erase the values, which is not good. Moreover, `Cookie` can only store `string` values.

Comment: @DatVM and memory only store bytes - your point about string?

Answer (score 0):

Use [dependency injection](http://blog.2mas.xyz/asp-net-5-ioc-and-dependency-injection/) and [Inversion of Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921087.aspx).  Most IOC tools, like Castle Windsor, will allow you to have your context persisted for the life of a request.

If you are not familiar with DI, here is a simple example:

```
Mycontroller
{
   IMyContext _contex;
   public Mycontroller(IMyContext context)
   {
      _context = context;
   }
}
```